# How do I send javascript event from webbrowser wpf control to c# code of wpf

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

Please help to solve this problem. This is my code:

```
private void MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender,     NavigationEventArgs e)
{                       
    mshtml.HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event iEvent;
    iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event)e;
    iEvent.onclick += new HTMLButtonElementEvents_onclickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);
}      

private bool ClickEventHandler()
{
    MessageBox.Show("WPF Event Handler");
    return true;
}
```

This is the code of the browser in WPF control. It works properly, but I can't use events in browser to invoke c# code.

Answer (score 0):

```
iEvent.onclick += (delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("WPF Event Handler");
    return true;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. May be I shoul create another method, not MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted?